# Can't ping domain from k8s pod

Tags: kubernetes, localhost, microk8s

I installed microk8s locally on my laptop from https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-a-local-kubernetes-with-microk8s#1-overview, the problem is I can't ping a restricetd domain from pod, but I am able from localhost and docker container with `--network host`.

*I want the pod inherits the same network behavior as in my localhost (`Bridging`)*

**From localhost**, I got

```
$ ping x.y.z
  Réponse de 10.88.255.60 : octets=32 temps=10 ms TTL=61
  Réponse de 10.88.255.60 : octets=32 temps=9 ms TTL=61
```

**From Docker container**

`without --network host`, I got an error

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh busybox:latest

$ ping x.y.z
  ping: bad address 'x.y.z'
```

`Using --network host`, I got

```
docker run -it --network host --entrypoint /bin/sh busybox:latest

$ ping x.y.z
  64 bytes from 10.88.255.60: seq=0 ttl=60 time=15.947 ms
  64 bytes from 10.88.255.60: seq=1 ttl=60 time=10.395 ms
```

**From microk8s pod**

To test my cluster, I launched a bogus container

```
kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh
```

The pod is launching perfectly

```
kubectl get pods
NAME      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
busybox   1/1     Running   0          17m
```

I got an error

```
# ping x.y.z
  ping: bad address 'x.y.z'
```

**NB:**
url `x.y.z` is bogus because I can't put the real url of the API (restricted acces).

**kubectl cluster-info**

```
 Kubernetes master is running at https://127.0.0.1:16443
 Heapster is running at https://127.0.0.1:16443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy
 CoreDNS is running at https://127.0.0.1:16443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
 Grafana is running at https://127.0.0.1:16443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana/proxy
 InfluxDB is running at https://127.0.0.1:16443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb:http/proxy
 To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

Comment: What is kubectl cluster-info saying?

Comment: I add the output of the command `kubectl cluster-info`

Comment: Did you use a dns provider for dns x.y.z? As an alternative you could try to dig your domain with the external DNS. inside the pod I mean

Comment: All I know is a `bridging` problem, for example in Docker we add `--network host ` for the container behaves like the local machine, but I dont know how to do this in microk8s

Comment: What do you mean by "Private API"? is this private API running on k8s's cluster?

Comment: ** `Private API`; reffering to restricted public acces.

** No, is an external API

Comment: I updated the question to avoid misunderstanding, hope it's clearer now. Sorry

Comment: That's is basically Kubernetes manages his own network environment, so your pod are in a network bubble that only can reach either other pods or only publics dns